# I bought a used surge suppressor. When I plugged in my laptop, I heard a "pop". Why?

Tags: power, sound, surge-protection

I bought a American Power Conversion Corp. surge-protecting power strip today. It's a seven-outlet model; I found it at the thrift store for $4. It appeared to be in decent condition, though I did drop it a few feet onto the hard floor shortly after buying it.

Late at night, the house was quiet. I plugged the device into the wall outlet and turned it on. The "Protection Working" LED lit up. Good.

I then plugged my laptop's AC adapter into the device. As I did so, I heard a "pop". The sound was a bit louder than a finger snap, but much quieter than a hand clap. My heart started racing.

Wondering if I damaged anything, I turned the laptop on. Thank God, it still works perfectly.

What could have caused the "pop" sound? Should I continue to use the power strip, or should I discard it?

---

Edit: This question has been closed. **To see more answers,** please visit ["Why did my surge suppressor make a 'pop' sound when I plugged something in?"](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/27023/why-did-my-surge-suppressor-make-a-pop-sound-when-i-plugged-something-in) on the Home Improvement Stack Exchange website.

Comment: "*My heart started racing*" made me laugh. Now that's an *unforgettable* statement for a typically terse and technical site such as this. :-)

Comment: Voting to close this question: *This question is ambiguous, ... incomplete, ... and cannot be reasonably answered in its current form. For help clarifying this question so that it can be reopened, [see the FAQ](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/faq#close).*

Comment: Besides that, it's also off topic: we don't deal with consumer electronics ([faq]). [su] is the place to go for that, but you'll have to ask a well formulated question.

Comment: Sounds like you got what you paid for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Surge suppressors contain components which if they fail are designed to 'fail safe'.

So your power strip is probably 'safe', but not suppressing surges.

I would strongly recommend that you discard it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. What could have caused the "pop"? Also, why do you think the device isn't suppressing surges?

Comment: Without looking inside it's impossible to tell what went 'pop'. Whatever component it was had a function, and now it's not doing that function. It could have been doing surge protection, or more importantly it might have had a safety related purpose. If you are not experienced in repairing line voltage equipment I would suggest you throw this away asap.